# Visual Studio Code Docker React TypeScript syntax highlighting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

I have a React & TypeScript & Docker project set up and it all works great. However, my Visual Studio Code is reporting various errors, like missing types and similar.

How to make the highlighting work?

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using docker, even if your folder is synchronised with a folder inside your docker image with volumes key, the node_modules is not a folder that is synchronized. But VScode, need them locally, without them, it can't do all this indexing things.

Generally, a docker-compose file look like this (the one you provide is perfectly fine)

```yaml
version: '3.1'
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

The volume option on node_modules "prevent" synchronization on this folder between local and the images. So, I simply do an `npm install` or `yarn` in the local folder.
Your image will normally not be impacted